# Integrate Cassandra with PHP (vTiger / SugarCRM)

Tags: php, cassandra, sugarcrm, vtiger

I am looking for documentation which will help me to integrate [Cassandra](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/) and VTiger.

Basically I have PHP based CRM which has huge amount of data and recently I just heard about Cassandra. I am using MySQL database for it. Please share the tutorials or documentation if you have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify the question. "help me to integrate Cassandra and VTiger" is too **vague**. And people just don't know what is **VTiger**

Comment: @doanduyhai: Post updated.

Comment: SO is a programming website, not an advice guide. Stick with google and search with correct keywords.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested by Cassandra, there is one **important** thing to understand, its architecture is completely different from relational DBs like MySQL although the query language (CQL) does look very similar to SQL.

I suggest:

1. Watch my Cassandra introduction slides to have a quick overview how it works: http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/cassandra-introduction-2016-60292046
2. Sign up (it's **free**) at http://academy.datastax.com and watch DS101 & DS220 modules it's fundamental if you want your migration from MySQL to be successful

Comment: Thank you for your response friend. One basic question I need to ask. As we are using MySQL for our CRM then do we need to completely remove Mysql and migrate with Cassandra or we need to just integrate Cassandra with MySQL?

Comment: Just gone through with the few tutorials.. ITs good! Its understandable!

Comment: If you're happy with MySQL and it works do not change. The only reason to move to Cassandra is that you expect an increase for your data and MySQL cannot scale anymore. In that case if you migrate to Cassandra you'll have to re-write the data access layer to use Cassandra and it is not trivial so think twice before taking decision